# how to install and run AR Cut & Paste?

Tags: applications

I found this interesting thing - AR Cut & Paste, but I don't know how to install and run correctly(on pc and android)?
On rooted android (s7 edge) I have installed termux, pyhton 3.8, nodjs (to run npm commands).
On PC windows 7, my video card is old but it has support of CUDA - nvidia GT 9500.
Of course, I have read "readme" files but I need more detailed steps if it's possible. for example, what command is written in app section "npm install" - what/how to install...?

Here is link about AR Cut & Paste - https://www.androidauthority.com/ar-cut-and-paste-1114757/
and here is link of app - https://github.com/cyrildiagne/ar-cutpaste

Comment: The GitHub project states that it not a consumer-app. Which means effectively that you need to compile the app yourself. Hence you need the Android SDK and usually Android Studio (compiling via gradle is also possible the you don't need Android Studio).

Comment: can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: Sorry but the app is based React Native - an ugly framework I won't touch. Please read the install manual yourself: https://github.com/cyrildiagne/ar-cutpaste/tree/master/app plus the server: https://github.com/cyrildiagne/ar-cutpaste/tree/master/server (ssem you need both).